# Java DNS cache size

Tags: java, dns

I'm writing an application which will be contacting a lot of web sites regularly (at their owners request). For this I'd like to be able to tune Java's DNS cache. I can't seem to find anywhere:

1. The default maximum cache size
2. How to change this

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**Edit**: I was concerned about the cache getting to large and running out of memory

Comment: It doesn't have a minimum or maximum size, it has entry TTLs. See [Networking Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html#nct).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a DNS server, installed on some server, with caching functionality.

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/DNS-HOWTO-3.html

https://superuser.com/questions/129484/what-is-a-good-local-windows-dns-caching-server-service

Comment: No you won't, Java has a DNS cache built in, see other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Java just delegates to the OS. What OS are you using?

Update: that's actually not completely true. The Sun JVM maintains its own cache of resolved hostnames. By default, items in the cache live forever, but you can adjust the [TTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/net/properties.html) downward. Of course, this cache does not persist across JVM invocations; in that case my first sentence stands.

Comment: @Pangea - Never used it myself; after posting I remembered that InetAddress did in fact have something internal, so took a look. I don't think that it's what the OP wants, however.

Comment: It's the InetAddress internal cache I'm looking at.

Comment: @Jonathan - it would have been useful if you'd said in your OP that you were worried about caching *too many* resolved names. I was assuming that you were worried about wasting time on DNS lookups as items aged out of the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through the [implementation](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/net/InetAddress.java.html) for the cache in InetAddress and I'm pretty sure there actually isn't a cache limit. I guess the designers never envisaged that a client could access so many hosts that this would cause us to run out of memory.